# is there a way to ask IDEA not to align method when multiline?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

when return type is very long because use complex generic types such like the follwoing

```java
public static <M extends Model, I extends InputStream, O extends OuputStream>
methodName(...){
...
}
```

, I have to put the methodName at the next line. But Idea will align it with `public` and cause checkstyle-plugin report error. If I put them in one line, checkstyle-plugin will report too-long error....

so can I change the setting of IDEA to solve the problem?

Comment: Just disable that *check-style* plugin then. Seems like it's not the IDEA, but the plugin reports an error.

Comment: Not really related, but why do you need specific types for `InputStream` and `OutputStream`?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri it's not my own project so I cant ask to disable the check-style plugin.(and the plugin is provided by my company, not by IDEA)..

Comment: @JoachimSauer it is just an example, the real code has nothing same as it except that it also use complex generic type...

Comment: @goushiso then you're looking to override plugin's behaviour?

Comment: You should submit a bug report to the one responsible for the checkstyle-plugin.